# I Need Help Generating a Table of Effects

Tags: campaign-development

I am writing a one-off campaign that involves an illusion where if the character dies they come back with a random affliction, such as "convinced they are invisible." I want it to be primarily populated by things that are roleplayed instead of direct stat penalties. However I am having trouble coming up with ideas to populate the table (this is my first time DM-ing anything!). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Idea-generation questions are unfortunately off topic. As a rule they don't work in the Stack Exchange site format, as they don't fit into its voting system. For questions like this what you actually want is a chat room or discussion forum instead. We have put together [a list of RPG discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) that you can consult for ideas of where to ask this.